# Number of ways to arrange a set of numbers

Tags: math, combinatorics

I have two numbers say **a** and **b**. There are **n** slots. Given numbers [**a**, **b**] i.e. all numbers between **a** and **b** (inclusive). In how mane ways can I arrange or place these (**b** - **a** + 1) numbers in these **n** slots such that there is at least 1 **a** **AND** at least 1 **b** in these **n** slots.

Example: If **a** = 1, and **b** = 5, and there are **n** = 4 slots. In how many ways can I arrange or place numbers {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} in these 4 slots, such that there is atleast one 1 and atleast one 5 in the set of 4 slots ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your problem correctly, but I'll give it a shot.

If a = b, you have only 1 solution, that is to say {a, a, a, ...a}.

If a < b and n = 1, there is no way of allocating the numbers the way you want.

If a < b and n > 1, you need to allocate 2 slots for them. There are n*(n-1) ways of doing that (when a slot is allocated to a, there are only n-1 possibilities left for b).
The other slots can be allocated to any numbers, and there are (b-a+1)^(n-2) possibilities.

So the answer is n*(n-1)*(b-a+1)^(n-2).